# Predicting sequence of sets

Tags: machine-learning, python, predictive-models, recurrent-neural-network

I have dataset which contains users and their market baskets (itemsets). The goal is to predict next basket. 
Can I predict next itemset in sequence of sets (itemsets) using RNN or another NN? Like next word in phrace. 
For example:

```
   1. array([ 23, 394, 389,  24,   9]),
   2. array([  9, 396,  31,  54,  41,  14]),
   3. array([389,  23,  77, 396, 394,  54]),
   4. array([ 54,   9,  14, 169, 394]),
   5. array([  9,  77, 394,  31,  54,  61, 808,  24,  23])
   next -> array([ 23, 389,  19,  41, 394,  77,   9,  31])
```

Is there working example of NN, that looks for patterns and tries to predict next set? 
I've found several researches e.g. [Using purchase histories for predicting
the next market basket by Octavian Maradin](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiu07TvoojyAhWUy4sKHe-cCwEQFjAAegQIBhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fthesis.eur.nl%2Fpub%2F53558%2F472761thesis.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0Qw97dltLA_1yt_zXcOln9) but there's no implementaions in Python.

Comment: So... if that research solves your problem, why not write an implementation in python?

Comment: I can't, i'm noob